# Trimming the actual pdf rather than showing trims with memoir

Tags: memoir, pdf-with-trim

I have a document in the memoir class and would like to produce a pdf that is trimmed at the edges (rather than just showing the trim lines in the pdf). In other words, the pdf should just be the actual size marked by the trims and no trims visible.

Here is my example.

```
\documentclass[showtrims,a4paper,twoside,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\setstocksize{28cm}{22cm}
\settrimmedsize{24cm}{17cm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{19cm}{12cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{2.5cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{*}
\settrims{20mm}{20mm}
\setmarginnotes{0em}{0cm}{0cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.25cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0cm}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
\fixpdflayout
\quarkmarks

\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Then why don't you set the stock size to the trimmed size to begin with?

Comment: @alephzero remember to trim when you use setstocksize, just trim it to stockheight and stockwidth. That mwe is not the stock size it is a4

Comment: @daleif OK, got it! I've revised my answer.

Comment: @alephzero it's even easier use `\stockwidth` and friend, no need to type the value twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `\stocksize` and the `\trimmedsize` both to the PDF page size, remove the paper size specification from the `\documentclass`, and (obviously) remove the trim marks etc.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} % to create some text for testing

\setstocksize{24cm}{17cm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settypeblocksize{19cm}{12cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{2.5cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0em}{0cm}{0cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.25cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0cm}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\lipsum % print some random text

\end{document}
```

Comment: As daleif said `memoir`s `\setstocksize` does the task. No need for the `geometry` package.

Comment: Actually the size info in the class options are just overwritten, one can leave it in, but it contributes nothing. It's stocksize and trimmedsize that are important